# MapStruct object inheritance mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a given scenario like below

```
> class Curve {
      private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
  }

> class Points {
      private Axis xAxis;
      private Axis yAxis;
      private Axis zAxis;
   }

> abstract class Axis {}

> class XAxis extends Axis {}
> class YAxis extends Axis {}
> class ZAxis extends Axis {}
```

I am creating a Mapper for Curve class like :

```
@Mapper
public interface CurveMapper {

 CurveMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMappers(CurveMapper.class);
 
 com.entity.Curve map(com.dto.Curve dtoCurve);    

}
```

> The build fails asking for concrete class/Object factory for `Axis`
> class.

I can add the `objectFactory` for Axis class but how can I map all 3 different concrete classes by single `objectFactory`.

Comment: Shouldn't `XAxis`,  `YAxis` and `ZAxis` extend `Axis`?

Comment: @Marc Yes, they are extending it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution obviously is to use concrete types on classes:

```
> class Curve {
      private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
  }

> class Points {
      private XAxis xAxis;
      private YAxis  yAxis;
      private ZAxis zAxis;
   }

> abstract class Axis {}

> class XAxis extends Axis{}
> class YAxis extends Axis{}
> class ZAxis extends Axis{}
```

Otherwise you should have a look in [qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers)

Define the following class:

```
public class AxisMapper {

    public Axis xAxis(AxisDto dto) {
        // some mapping logic, including new object creation
    }

}
```

Define the qualifier for general axis handling:

```
import org.mapstruct.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface AxisTranslator{
}
```

And the qualifier for methods (one per axis):

```
import org.mapstruct.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface XAxis{
}
```

Decorate your custom mapper:

```
@AxisTranslator
public class AxisMapper {

    @XAxis
    public Axis xAxis(AxisDto dto) {
        // some mapping logic, including new object creation
    }

}
```

And then, add this new mapper to your one:

```
@Mapper(uses = AxisMapper.class)
public interface CurveMapper {

 CurveMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMappers(CurveMapper.class);
 
 @Mapping( target = "xAxis", qualifiedBy = { AxisTranslator.class, XAxis.class } )
 com.entity.Curve map(com.dto.Curve dtoCurve);    

}
```

Do the same for Y and Z axis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't work here. I tried this way.

Comment: Same error asking for concrete class/Object factory for Axis class

Comment: I got this resolved though with Spring Component class having instance of check and used it in mapper class.